# What is the context passed to a broadcast receiver and contentprovider?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-contentprovider, android-context

`Activity` and `Service` inherit from `Context` while `BroadcastReceiver` and `ContentProvider` do not.
The `BroadcastReceiver` gets a `Content` in the `onReceive()` method while in the `ContentProvider` a `Context` is available via the `getContext()`.
My question is, what is the source of these contexts? How are they created?
I mean when our code runs in an activity or service since both are subclasses of a `Context` it is pretty clear what's going on.
But what exactly are the context's used by the other two components?

Comment: "what is the source of these contexts?" -- that could vary by OS version or device manufacturer.

Comment: @CommonsWare: What would be the possible variations? I would be ok with the flow as an answer. It is not clear to me exactly what's going on and these 2 components end up having some valid context from somewhere

Comment: Well, `Context` is an abstract class. The `Context` that you get could be the `Application` singleton, or a `ContextWrapper` around the `Application` singleton, or potentially some other implementation of the `Context` abstract class. There is no requirement for it to be anything in particular, other than to extend from `Context`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: What is the point of those 2 components not extending `Context` then? What is the idea of the design?

Comment: Questions of the form "why did Developer X make Decision Y?" generally are not good for Stack Overflow. Frequently, only Developer X can answer, and Developer X is unlikely to see your questions. In this case, it was an API decision made by some Google engineers ~14 years ago.

Comment: @CommonsWare: To ask in another way. When an event is fired the broadcast receiver will get it regardless if there are 0 activities running. I assume in this case the only context available would be the Application context. Based on this reasoning, could there ever by a case that the Application context would not be passed? Could some activity's context be passed in if some is running? Is there a 3rd type of context that I am not aware of?

Comment: "could there ever by a case that the Application context would not be passed?" -- sure. It could be a `ContextWrapper` around `Application`, or some other `Context` subclass that you have not seen before. "Could some activity's context be passed in if some is running?" -- that would surprise me. "Is there a 3rd type of context that I am not aware of?" -- there is `ContextWrapper` and `MutableContextWrapper` and `ContextImpl` in the framework, just off the top of my head. A small percentage of the classes that exist are in the SDK. Plus, your tests will use mock/fake `Context` objects.

Comment: Wouldn't that unknown derived instance be some wrapper for the `Application`? It seems that the `Application` would be the only real Context available? Or is this an implementation detail we can not be sure?

Comment: "Wouldn't that unknown derived instance be some wrapper for the Application?" -- not necessarily. `Context` is an abstract class, and the framework can have as many subclasses of that as it wants. I repeat: *a small percentage of the classes that exist are in the SDK*. Many more are in your process but are hidden. "Or is this an implementation detail we can not be sure?" -- never assume implementations when you are handed an abstraction (e.g., an `interface` or `abstract class` in Java).